# why skyfield satellite position reading calculations are different from n2yo?

Tags: python, satellite, skyfield, sgp4

I am trying to track the satellite and getting its location in form of latitude, longitude and height from TLE data.
But when I try to match it with the realtime readings on [n2yo](https://www.n2yo.com/) website, my latitude has difference of 5 degree and longitude difference of 12 degree on average. Height is exactly same

I am using the [skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) library to calculate location.
Here is the code that I am using.

```
def get_live_data(TLE):

    load = Loader('~/Documents/fishing/SkyData')
    data = load('de421.bsp')
    ts = load.timescale() 

    planets = load('de421.bsp')
    earth = planets['earth']

    ts = load.timescale()
    minutes = np.arange(0, 240, 2)

    L1, L2 = TLE.splitlines()
    CARTO_Geo = EarthSatellite(L1, L2)
    time = ts.now()
    geocentric = CARTO_Geo.at(time)
    lat, lon = wgs84.latlon_of(geocentric)
    h = wgs84.height_of(geocentric)
    time_str = f"{time.utc.hour}: {time.utc.minute}: {int(time.utc.second)}"
    position = {'lat': round(lat.degrees, 2), 'lon': round(lon.degrees, 2), 'height': round(h.km, 2), 'time': time_str}
    
    return position
```

**The "Epoch Date" of satellite TLE is 15-July-2023**

```
TLE : 
1 44804U 19081A   23196.35840878  .00005378  00000+0  25694-3 0  9994
2 44804  97.3450 253.5493 0009838 278.3489  81.6631 15.19397374201298
```